# Emit coroutine Flow from Room while backfilling via network request

Tags: android, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I have my architecture like so:

1. Dao methods returning `Flow<T>`:

   ```
   @Query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = :id")
   fun itemById(id: Int): Flow<Item>
   ```
2. Repository layer returning items from DB but also backfilling from network:

   (* Need help here -- this is not working as intended **)

   ```
   fun items(): Flow<Item> = flow {
       // Immediately emit values from DB
       emitAll(itemDao.itemById(1))

       // Backfill DB via network request without blocking coroutine
       itemApi.makeRequest()
           .also { insert(it) }
   }
   ```
3. ViewModel layer taking the flow, applying any transformations, and converting it into a LiveData using .asLiveData():

   ```
   fun observeItem(): LiveData<Item> = itemRepository.getItemFlow()
       .map { // apply transformation to view model }
       .asLiveData()
   ```
4. Fragment observing LiveData emissions and updating UI:

   ```
   viewModel.item().observeNotNull(viewLifecycleOwner) {
       renderUI(it)
   }
   ```

The issue I'm having is at step 2. I can't seem to figure out a way to structure the logic so that I can emit the items from Flow immediately, but also perform the network fetch without waiting.

Since the fetch from network logic is in the same suspend function it'll wait for the network request to finish before emitting the results downstream. But I just want to fire that request independently since I'm not interested in waiting for a result (when it comes back, it'll update Room and I'll get the results naturally).

Any thoughts?

**EDIT**

Marko's solution works well for me, but I did attempt a similar approach like so:

```
suspend fun items(): Flow<List<Cryptocurrency>> = coroutineScope {
    launch {
        itemApi.makeRequest().also { insert(it) }
    }

    itemDao.itemById(1)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you're describing a background task that you want to launch. For that you need access to your coroutine scope, so `items()` should be an extension function on `CoroutineScope`:

```
fun CoroutineScope.items(): Flow<Item> {
    launch {
        itemApi.makeRequest().also { insert(it) }
    }
    return flow {
        emitAll(itemDao.itemById(1))
    }
}
```

On the other hand, if you'd like to start a remote fetch whose result will also become a part of the response, you can do it as follows:

```
fun items(): Flow<Item> = flow {
    coroutineScope {
        val lateItem = async { itemApi.makeRequest().also { insert(it) } }
        emitAll(itemDao.itemById(1))
        emit(lateItem.await())
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Marko! Option 1 was what I was looking for.

I attempted a similar approach before asking this question (check out the edit). Looks very similar to your solution but waits for the operation in launch to finish before continuing. If you have time to explain why it would help me and future readers. Cheers!

Comment: Also, wouldn't you want to move the async operation to Dispatchers.IO to take it off the Main dispatcher? The flow coming from room is ultimately transformed to a LiveData, so that being on Main makes sense.

Comment: There are two choices: 1. use a local `coroutineScope` and don't return until the `launch`ed coroutine completes; 2. use a long-running scope you defined on the outside and return without waiting for it to complete. It's up to you to see which one fits you better.

Comment: As for `Dispatchers.IO`, my hope was you were using a non-blocking networking API on Android. If for some reason you're trapped into using a blocking API then yes, you must resort to a wasteful IO thread pool.